# What is the proper syntax for ".Stop" method for "Schedule.Service"?

Tags: vbscript

I have some tasks that need to be removed. Some users have installed Chrome under their own profile and the only way to remove it is to "nuke" it since it is not feasible to log in with their account and do the uninstall the proper way. The scheduled tasks have a user sid added to the end of the name, so I have to search for a task with "GoogleUpdate" in the string. When I remove a service, I like to stop the service, disable the service, then delete it. I want to do the same thing with the scheduled tasks. After a lot of scouring of the web, I have found the syntax to disable, delete and that works perfect, but not how to stop. I would prefer not to shell out and use schtasks since I have come this far with a 200 + line script using all VbScript.
Here is what I have so far. I need help figuring out the syntax for the ".Stop" method. If anyone has an example of the stop method, it would be much appreciated.

```
Set objTaskService = CreateObject("Schedule.Service")
Call objTaskService.Connect()
Set objTaskFolder = objTaskService.GetFolder("\")
Set colTasks = objTaskFolder.GetTasks(0)
For Each objTask In colTasks
  With objTask
    If InStr(.Name, "GoogleUpdate") Then
      objTask.Stop() << Wrong number of args or invalid property assignment
      WScript.Sleep(10000)
      objTask.Enabled = False << Working properly
      objTaskFolder.DeleteTask objTask.Name,0  << Working properly
    End If
  End With
Next
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382125(v=vs.85).aspx. A better way to find the running tasks is also at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382126(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official documentation is located here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382098(v=vs.85).aspx

> RegisteredTask.Stop(ByVal flags)
>
> Parameters
>
> flags [in]
>           Reserved.
>           
>       Must be zero.

Hence, it should be

`objTask.Stop 0`